# How would I use a wrapper class to call methods within a main?

Tags: java, methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Double ans1 = add(5, 9);
     Number ans2 = add(new Integer(3), new Double(2.4));
     double ans3 = add(10, 3.2);
     System.out.println(answer1 + " " + answer2 + " " + answer3);
   }
```

Given the main method above, how would I create a static method (as opposed a set of overloaded methods) which in turn would could successfully call the methods within the main?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do u want to move the code to a static method ?

Comment: Nope, the code that is there is to stay put in the main. I simply need to write a static method that can be called by ALL of those methods in the main. Apologies, I'm not that profound at java!

Comment: Sorry, but you need to be clearer, and use the appropriate terminology. A method doesn't contain other methods. It contains instructions. Post a complete example of what you want, because I can't understand anything to what you're asking.

Comment: You call `YourMainClass.main()`, or are you referring to the `add` method that we cannot see?

Comment: @Alex, I think you are confused between overloading and static

Comment: The question I have been asked is as follows:

**'Given the following main method, write a single static method (not a set of overloaded methods) which can be called successfully by all the methods in main.'**

Maybe the way its written has confused me and in turn you guys as well! @javaguy

Answer (score 0):

> write a single static method (not a set of overloaded methods) which
>   can be called successfully by all the methods in main.

It is very basic, you can simply do that by creating a new `static` `add()` method (a single method contains the code for all calls to different overloaded `add` methods) as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     add();
}
public static void add() {
     Double ans1 = add(5, 9);
     Number ans2 = add(new Integer(3), new Double(2.4));
     double ans3 = add(10, 3.2);
     System.out.println(answer1 + " " + answer2 + " " + answer3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I understand what your teacher wants, despite the wrong terminology he's using. He wants you to write a unique static add() method. And the code should compile and run after this unique add() method is being added to the code.

Since the method is called with arguments that are of type int, Integer, Double and double, the argument types must be a parent class of all these types (after boxing/unboxing). For example Number, or Object.

Since the returned value is assigned to a variable of type Double, Number and double, the return type must be a common class or subclass subclass of all this (after boxing/unboxing).

A candidate would thus be, for example:

```
private static double add(Object i, Object i1) {
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the `ansX` variables need to be renamed to `answerX`, too, otherwise the code will never compile.

I guess we can also safely assume that `add()` should add the arguments. I leave that as an exercise for your.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the `add` method to be called successfully by the `main` method, you need to figure out what types to use for the return value and the parameters.

Here's a template:

```
private static ??? add(??? a, ??? b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

As you can see, `main` calls `add` with all kinds of arguments, and it stores the result in different types of variables as well.

If you analyze the `main` method, you will see that the `add` method must be able to accept the following types of parameters:

```
(int, int)
(Integer, Double)
(int, double)
```

It can be deduced that an `int`, a `double`, an `Integer` and a `Double` can be implicitly converted to the parameters' type. If you do a little bit of thinking, you will know that `double` is one of the types that satisfy this requirement. This means that the parameters can be of tyoe `double`!

And it must be able to return a value that's compatible with the following types:

```
Double
double
Number
```

It can be deduced that the return type must be able to be implictly converted to `Double`, `double`, or `Number`. `double` also satisfy this requirement. This means that the method returns a double as well!

Here's the completed method:

```
private static double add(double a, double b) {
    return a + b;
}
```